# Perl Install PAR:Packer Problems

Tags: perl, installation, perl-module, par, packer

My perl version is 5.16.2 on my Windows 7 64bit, I failed to install PAR:Packer. I tried active perl and strawberry perl , both got the same error. Can you please give me some suggestion. Below is my experience:

I tried `ppm install PAR:Packer`, version 1.013, But when I use pp, I got the error:

```
Perl lib version (5.16.2) doesn't match executable version (v5.16.0).
```

I also tried `cpan install PAR:Packer`, version 1.014. But I got the error during installation. The pop up window says: `par.exe has stopped working`. Then command prompt got the error:

```
C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe -Mblib run_with_inc.pl par.exe -q -B -Oparldyn.exe
system(par.exe -I C:\Users\PAR-Packer-1.014\blib\arch -I C:\Users\PAR-Packer-1.014\blib\lib -     IC:/Perl64/site/lib -IC:/Perl64/lib -I. -q -B -Oparldyn.exe) failed:
dmake.exe:  Error code 255, while making 'parldyn.exe'
dmake.exe:  Error code 255, while making 'subdirs'
```

I have googled extensively, but as of yet haven't been able to find a solution, any help is greatly appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: From what you are writing i assume you use ActivePerl. You might have better luck trying a fresh install of [StrawberryPerl](http://strawberryperl.com/) since many module authors try to actively support that distribution.

Comment: I tried both ActivePerl and StrawberryPerl, but got the same errors when using cpan install PAR:Packer

Comment: Could be that pp is using the wrong interpreter. Have you checked the environment? Especially the PATH variable? The error message seems to point in that direction. Also, the portable version of Strawberry Perl might be worth a try, since that usualy does a nice job of isolating the portable version from other perls on your system.

Comment: I uninstalled the active perl completely when installing strawberry perl. I checked the path variable, it is correct.

Comment: I will try the portable version of Strawberry Perl.

Answer (score 4):

I simply changed the line 60 in .../perl64/Config.pm from

```
`$^V eq 5.16.3`
```

to

```
`$^V eq 5.16.3 or $^V eq 5.16.0`
```

and voila! My par-packer module 1.013 installed through ppm (ActiveState Perl 5.16.3) works ...

Answer (score 1):

I'll start off with my own environment:

- Windows 7 x64 en_US
- Strawberry Perl v5.16.2 32bit

I just confirmed that I do have PAR::Packer working on my environment. I'm running PAR::Packer version 1.014.

There is a bug logged about PAR::Packer 1.013 failing to build on certain environments. The bug is logged on CPAN here: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=77408

I recommend trying one of the following paths forward (based on your build version requirements):

1. Install PAR::Packer 1.0.14.
2. Install the patched version of PAR::Packer 1.013 that is available at http://strawberryperl.com/package/kmx/perl-modules-patched/PAR-Packer-1.013_patched.tar.gz

To build you will need any dependencies as well. Hopefully those work just fine through CPAN.

Download either the patched version listed above or the latest version from the CPAN site, then execute:

```
perl Makefile.pl
dmake
dmake test
dmake install
```

Keep in mind PAR::Packer requires a C/C++ compiler to build.

Comment: When I run dmake, I got the same error: par.exe stopped working. dmake.exe:  Error code 255, while making 'parldyn.exe'
dmake.exe:  Error code 255, while making 'subdirs'

Comment: Works for http://strawberryperl.com/download/5.16.2.2/strawberry-perl-5.16.2.2-32bit-portable.zip and `PAR::Packer 1.0.25`. (`cpanm PAR::Packer`)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same error scenario with Perl 5.16.3 on my Windows 7 64 bit machine.  I started my Perl tinkering with ActiveState and later installed other related programs like Komodo Edit and finally installed StrawberryPerl.  After reading quite a few of these online posts I tried the manual dmake methods and whatever other suggestions I could find.  I then tried uninstalling ActiveState.  That didn't help either.  Finally, I went on an uninstall binge and found that after uninstalling all of the ActiveState and Komodo applications (along with a bunch of other stuff I wasn't using anymore) I was able to successfully install and use pp in two simple steps from the cpan prompt:

install CPAN

install pp

I was going to uninstall and re-install StrawberryPerl next but didn't have to.  The install CPAN may not be necessary but it was suggested in the log output in one of my previously failed attempts so I figured I'd try that first.  Hope this saves someone all the hassle I went to as a begginer.